# PostgreSQL. Low count(*)-select performance with additional left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, database-performance

I have this select:

```
SELECT count(*) AS y0_
FROM erc.SUBJECTS this_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fias.FIAS_HOUSE factaddres4_ ON this_.FACTADDRESS_REF = factaddres4_.houseId
  LEFT OUTER JOIN fias.FIAS_AGREGATE_ADDRESS factaddres5_ ON factaddres4_.houseId = factaddres5_.HOUSEID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN erc.REFITEMS okopf_1_ ON this_.OKOPF_REF = okopf_1_.ID
WHERE this_.IS_ACTUAL = 1 AND this_.IS_DELETE <> 1 AND NOT okopf_1_.CODE LIKE '5%' AND NOT okopf_1_.CODE = '0'
```

It runs for almost 18 seconds.

subjects table has 376k rows, fias_house has 21 million rows, fias_agregate_address - 130.
explain analyze result:

```
Aggregate  (cost=1061561.33..1061561.34 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=17813.460..17813.460 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=106687.31..1060683.61 rows=351088 width=4) (actual time=763.556..17741.820 rows=376196 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((factaddres4_.houseid)::text = (factaddres5_.houseid)::text)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=106679.25..1059358.95 rows=351088 width=41) (actual time=760.772..17599.742 rows=376196 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (this_.okopf_ref = okopf_1_.id)
              ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=106599.85..1053887.84 rows=376166 width=45) (actual time=759.211..17411.313 rows=376254 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: ((factaddres4_.houseid)::text = (this_.factaddress_ref)::text)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using fias_house_pkey on fias_house factaddres4_  (cost=0.56..924229.05 rows=21084566 width=37) (actual time=0.013..8528.487 rows=19627484 loops=1)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=74125.25..76006.08 rows=376166 width=45) (actual time=759.171..980.286 rows=376254 loops=1)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=74125.25..75065.67 rows=376166 width=45) (actual time=759.167..863.495 rows=376254 loops=1)
                                Sort Key: this_.factaddress_ref
                                Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 6616kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on subjects this_  (cost=0.00..27715.88 rows=376166 width=45) (actual time=0.790..591.380 rows=376254 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((is_delete <> 1) AND (is_actual = 1))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 138
              ->  Hash  (cost=53.85..53.85 rows=2044 width=4) (actual time=1.522..1.522 rows=2051 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on refitems okopf_1_  (cost=0.00..53.85 rows=2044 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.930 rows=2051 loops=1)
                          Filter: (((code)::text !~~ '5%'::text) AND ((code)::text <> '0'::text))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 139
        ->  Hash  (cost=6.36..6.36 rows=136 width=37) (actual time=2.761..2.761 rows=136 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
              ->  Seq Scan on fias_agregate_address factaddres5_  (cost=0.00..6.36 rows=136 width=37) (actual time=1.477..2.696 rows=136 loops=1)
Total runtime: 17814.728 ms
```

Without joining FIAS_AGREGATE_ADDRESS request completes for more adequate time. Explain analyze result:

```
Aggregate  (cost=34066.40..34066.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=510.291..510.292 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=79.40..33188.44 rows=351183 width=4) (actual time=1.573..442.526 rows=376196 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (this_.okopf_ref = okopf_1_.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on subjects this_  (cost=0.00..27715.88 rows=376267 width=45) (actual time=0.144..248.430 rows=376254 loops=1)
              Filter: ((is_delete <> 1) AND (is_actual = 1))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 138
        ->  Hash  (cost=53.85..53.85 rows=2044 width=4) (actual time=1.415..1.415 rows=2051 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
              ->  Seq Scan on refitems okopf_1_  (cost=0.00..53.85 rows=2044 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.844 rows=2051 loops=1)
                    Filter: (((code)::text !~~ '5%'::text) AND ((code)::text <> '0'::text))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 139
Total runtime: 510.367 ms
```

I found this article: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting
But I can't use those advices, because search conditions could vary.

I also can't just throw away FIAS_AGREGATE_ADDRESS joining, because there could be search condition on that table.

Maybe there could be some clever index or other opportunity, that I missed because of tiredness and stupidity?

**UPD:** After increasing work_mem from 8MB to 16 explain analyze result became:

```
Aggregate  (cost=1018467.07..1018467.08 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=18615.975..18615.975 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=810328.24..1017589.11 rows=351183 width=4) (actual time=3.609..18543.596 rows=376196 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((factaddres4_.houseid)::text = (factaddres5_.houseid)::text)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=810320.18..1016264.10 rows=351183 width=41) (actual time=2.190..18400.383 rows=376196 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (this_.okopf_ref = okopf_1_.id)
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=810240.78..1010791.53 rows=376267 width=45) (actual time=0.838..18203.533 rows=376254 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: ((this_.factaddress_ref)::text = (factaddres4_.houseid)::text)
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_subjects_factaddress_ref_btree on subjects this_  (cost=0.42..32907.70 rows=376267 width=45) (actual time=0.805..701.428 rows=376254 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using fias_house_pkey on fias_house factaddres4_  (cost=0.56..924231.15 rows=21084706 width=37) (actual time=0.013..8885.002 rows=19627486 loops=1)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Hash  (cost=53.85..53.85 rows=2044 width=4) (actual time=1.307..1.307 rows=2051 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on refitems okopf_1_  (cost=0.00..53.85 rows=2044 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.802 rows=2051 loops=1)
                          Filter: (((code)::text !~~ '5%'::text) AND ((code)::text <> '0'::text))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 139
        ->  Hash  (cost=6.36..6.36 rows=136 width=37) (actual time=1.396..1.396 rows=136 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
              ->  Seq Scan on fias_agregate_address factaddres5_  (cost=0.00..6.36 rows=136 width=37) (actual time=0.782..1.323 rows=136 loops=1)
Total runtime: 18616.060 ms
```

"Sort" row disappeared, but request time wasn't affected really.

There are foreign keys for every join. Mapped column everywhere is private key. I mean, for example, SUBJECTS table has FK: OKOPF_REF->REFITEMS.ID and ID is private key column in REFITEMS.

Here is link on ddl (including indexes) for those tables: https://yadi.sk/d/-OxGh5BDdy4XW.

I posted trimmed query for better analyze, but there are could be different search condition, like searching for a substring in different tables. I have this worst case: for simple search string (like '123') there are all joins (search should be executed on all tables), but still count result is very big. Because of it, I can't omit those left joins.

Comment: Note, when OUTER JOIN, put the conditions for the outer tables  (NOT okopf_1_.CODE etc) in the ON clauses, not in the WHERE clause. (Otherwise it's just a regular inner join.)

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, I will change to inner join in application, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: "Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 6616kB", work_mem is set too low, change it to at least 10MB and try again. Disk sort should be avoided, it's slow.

Comment: How many matching rows do you expect (per {SUBJECTS} row) from the three left-joined tables {FIAS_HOUSE factaddres4_,FIAS_AGREGATE_ADDRESS,REFITEMS} If this is never more than one, the left joins will not affect the total count (except for what @jarlh commented above) Adding (part of) the schema to the question will certainly help.

Comment: Note: given the fact that the left join is performed by {sort+sort+merge} , I suspect that there are no usable FK->PK couplings (or indexes) between the tables.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for advise, but it didn't affect much to overall time

Comment: @wildplasser I can't omit left join when there is other search condition for joined table. I also posted some info about schema. If you have an idea for some index, write it please. I experimented for some time with indexes, but couldn't speed up this query.

Comment: Questions about "slow queries" cannot be answered without the relevant table definitions. **PLEASE ADD YOUR TABLE DEFINITIONS (INCLUDING INDEXES) TO THE QUESTION. THANK YOU!**

Comment: @wildplasser here is link for ddl: https://yadi.sk/d/-OxGh5BDdy4XW

Comment: The link shows nothing.

Comment: @wildplasser It's because i saved it as .sql. You can download the file. All ddl for those tables took 693 rows. That's why I post it like a file.